Data difference at backend and Power BI in-memory
I have been working on a report in PowerBI. I have made a visual where I show "Bookings by consultant type". Now the problem is, when I check the same thing at the backend database, the values differ than what they are on the visual.
For example, there are 4359 female psychologist bookings at the backend, but in the visual, there are 4360 bookings.
What can cause this and how do I solve this issue? Thanks

If you use import mode, maybe you need to refresh the data. Check if the applied filters on both sides are exactly the same. If this does not solve the issue, try reducing the rows by filtering, and find which row you are missing. That way it will be much easier to establish the problem. I

I am using the ODBC connector. I have refreshed the data and yet the issue still persists. The filters on both sides are exactly the same.  Can you please elaborate the second part of your comment. Thanks

Apply more filters on both sides - PowerBI, and backend to reduce the rows, and find exactly which exact booking is missing in PBI. With 4359 rows it is very hard to identify it, but with 20-200 will be much easier.
